# Using Gnuplot splot with haskell list of tuples?

Tags: haskell, gnuplot

so i have gnu in haskell and want to graph 3d surfaces. From my understanding it seems like i would have to make a text file name data.txt and it having this

```
1 1 4
1 2 3
1 3 1
1 4 5
2 1 1
2 2 4
2 3 6
2 4 1
3 1 0
3 2 2
3 3 7
3 4 1
4 1 1
4 2 5
4 3 4
4 4 7
```

Then doing splot "data" with lines. however, i have a list in haskell, that contains tuples that represent each of these points. Does anyone know how i can make this work with my list rather than  putting my data in a text file somehow?

Comment: Can you add an example of your list of tuple in the question ?

Comment: [(1,2,3),(1,2,4)] just a list containing the tuple of points.

Comment: "so i have gnu in haskell" Do you mean that you have installed [the gnuplot package from Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot)?

Comment: Ive been using Graphs.Gnuplot.Advanced/Simple

Answer (score 4):

You can see the example given in the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot-0.5.2.2/docs/Graphics-Gnuplot-Simple.html#v:plotMesh3d):

```
λ> import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple
λ> let xs = [-2,-1.8..2::Double] in plotMesh3d [] [] (do x <- xs; return (do y <- xs; return (x,y,cos(x*x+y*y))))
```

That produces something like this:

[image]

Comment: i dont know what the function is, im solving a partial differential equation numerically, there is no plugging points into a function to get the z coordinate. I have a list of tuples where each tuple is a point

Comment: @Eigenvalue Looking at the examples listed, `plotMesh3d` seems to expect a list of lists of tuples with the list nesting corresponding to the grid pattern to draw. Assuming your x,y coordinates *do* form a grid, you might be able to get your tuple list into the form expected by `plotMesh3D` with ``groupBy ((==) `on` \(x,_,_) -> x) (sort yourTupleList)`` (`groupBy` and `sort` are from `Data.List`, `on` is from `Data.Function`.)

Comment: @Eigenvalue I went through the Gnuplot API and was not able to see any functions which will correlate with the following gnuplot command: `splot using 1:2:3 with linespoints` which is pretty unfortunate.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. I know where to go now.

Comment: @Eigenvalue You can add your answer here if you have found any other alternative method.

Comment: Worked for me! Simple and beautiful!