# Converting a haskell list of points into a file that can be called with splot

Tags: haskell, gnuplot

So i have a list full of tuples of 3 which contain the x y z coordinate of a point. I want to attempt to graph this with splot.

The command would be something like this if i had the file named data im pretty sure

```
splot "data" with lines
```

From my understanding the file needs to contain the points which im fine with, however the problem im having it it seems you need order these from least to greatest for the x values, which isnt a problem, however the other two components seem like for example you had 3 points, you have to have do all combinations of those last two coordinates with that x coordinate to get a surface?

I wasnt sure if that was the idea of this. Additionally if this is the case, to write a function that does this for a set of specific x points seems tricky for me with recursion,

can someone give me some tips if im even on the right direction?

Comment: This seems quite closely related to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108653/using-gnuplot-splot-with-haskell-list-of-tuples

Comment: Yes, the difference however is i actually want to do it instead of trying to find a magic function that will help me. Curious about knowing what needs to be in this data file in order for it to be a surface plot when i graph it.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to use [easyplot](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/easyplot) which also uses the same `gnuplot` backend for generating graphs. I find it's API more simple and useful than [gnuplot](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot).

Following code draws `(x,y,z)` coordinates:

```
import Graphics.EasyPlot

option = Data3D [Style Lines] [] [(1,1,4),(2,2,3),(1,3,1),(1,4,5),(2,2,1),(2,2,4),(2,3,6)]

main = plot X11 option
```

It produces a graph like this:

[image: haskell-graph]

You can add more styles to make it beautiful.

Comment: This is great, is there a way to make this a surface? or is it already in that format just not in that form?

Comment: @Eigenvalue I'm not sure what do you mean by surface here. Can you explain more ?